# Roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can a quadratic equation have irrational roots? By extension, can any equation have irrational roots? If not, why? If it can, how would you visualize it? (geometrically). I want to add that I am a high school school student. Don't want people wasting time writing answers that I can not understand

Comment: What do you mean by 'visualize' it?

Comment: Consider $x^2 = 2$

Comment: consider $x=\pi$

Comment: Do you know what an irrational number is?

Comment: Yes, one that can not be expressed as a ratio of two integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2 -a = 0$ will give alot of irrational numbers. An interesting fact is that if a is a prime, the solution will allways be an irrational number. I am not sure how you can visualize it, but $\sqrt{2} = 1.41421...$ The number will continue forever and you will never be able to get "onto it", just very close. Don't know any other way to look at it. therefor $(1.41421...)^2 -2 = 0.00000...$

Answer (score 0):

Sure $x^2 - 2$ has irrational roots.

Comment: I'm just having trouble picturing a line cutting the x axis at an infinite value. How can that happen?

Comment: I don't understand. Neither root here of $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$ is infinite, but they are irrational.

Comment: I meant an indefinite value

Comment: What's an indefinite value? What ever they may be, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are well defined.

Comment: What do you mean by well defined?

Comment: Until that time [Doron Zeilberger](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/real.pdf) finishes reformulating math in a truly finitistic way, I'm afraid you'll have to accept these sorts of things. sqrt(2) isn't actually that much of a big deal, there are other more serious issues that you'll have to get used to later.

Comment: I mean that in modern mathematics, $\sqrt{2}$ is well understood and characterized. If you lived 2,000+ years ago with the Pythagoreans, you would be very bothered, because they didn't know how to think about numbers that weren't rational. We've made some progress since then.